# Django CSRF Cookie Not Setting

Tags: django, csrf

I have been trying to set up CSRF protection on my POST forms on my django 1.4.3 site and have been getting the 403 CSRF cookie not set error.

I believe I have followed the doc in detail, followed advice on many forums but all to no avail. I have stripped back the code as much as possible and the cookie just does not set. The csrfmiddlewaretoken is present, so that's not the source of the problem. I'm at my wit's end. No doubt the answer is stupidly simple, I just need a fresh set of eyes to point it out to me...

So here's some code:

```
#urls.py
...
url(r'^csrf/$', csrf_test, name='csrf_test'),
...

#views.py
...
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
def csrf_test(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('csrf.html', c)
...

<!-- csrf.html -->
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

#settings.py
...
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (                
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    #for db transactions. Check middleware order if faulty
    'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)
...
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
...
```

I am running the django development server on 127.0.0.1:8000.

I have cookies enabled on my browsers and have confirmed cookies are being set from other websites.

I have checked the csrfmiddlewaretoken is being passed as a POST variable.

I always get the error, this is not intermittent.

I have no problem with POST forms when I have disabled the middleware/used @csrf_exempt.

As I say, I'm at my wit's end. What on earth have I missed?

Thanks

Nathan

EDIT:

It now works, but I have no idea what has changed. For anyone reading this in the future I created a new project and app, it created the cookie straight away. Thinking it must have been a settings issue I changed the order of my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES entries by moving 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' down below 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'. I ran the original app and it worked. However to test whether the settings change was responsible I reversed the change. It still worked. Go figure.

I hope this helps someone in the future FWIW.

Nathan

Comment: How about trying to step through the csrf code in a debugger itself to see what's happening (I'm at a loss really, but that's what I'd do next).

Comment: Cheers, will debug after work. Also might try starting a clean project in case some wierd setting I have introduced is causing issues.

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I'm having this problem too.

Comment: Nothing definitive. I ended up creating a brand new project and copied the code over. Worked as it should have done. A mystery

Answer (score 1):

if you're using render_to_response then you should probably use a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext)

This will handle the csrf protection for you -

```
def csrf_test(request):
    render_to_response('csrf.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You don't need to include the `csrf_protect` decorator, since you've got the csrf middleware.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer, but I have tried that with the same result.

Comment: Actaully I can't see anything wrong with your code (It's a bit unfamiliar to me as I've always used a RequestContext).

Comment: Cheers for looking it over, looked all good to me too, which is why I don't know what to test next. In my main code I am using a RequstContext, but the above example was my attempt at simplifying code for testing.

Comment: had a go at it: def csrf_test(request):
    return render(request, 'csrf.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request)) but still getting the same error. How does this code look (I haven't used render() before)?

Comment: render does the assignment to context_instance, so you don't have to worry about the RequestContext (it's a new alternative to render_to_response).

Answer (score 1):

```
def csrf_test(request):
    .....
    return render(request, 'csrf.html', { ..... })
```